# Built-in Constructors and their Prototype --

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, proto

The activity was to Log Array.prototype and Object.prototype to the console using only the arr variable and the **proto** property.

So these are the original code:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(); // log the Array.prototype
console.log(); // log the Object.prototype
```

So What I did: I wrote on the first, `console.log(arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype)`;
the second one is, `console.log(arr.__proto__ === Object.prototype)`; but still not right.
It says that in the first log, the Array.prototype is the **proto** property of any array. the next one, the prototype property of Array.prototype refers to the object.prototype. I can't figure it out what does it meant. I tried also writing like this: `console.log(arr.__proto__ === Object.prototype)`; still not right. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am confused at what you are wanting as it says to log the prototype but you are console logging comparisons between two object properties?

Comment: If what you want is to log the prototypes, try `console.log(arr.__proto__)` and `console.log(arr.__proto__._proto__)` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yeah. it actually works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.prototype === arr.__proto__);
console.log(Object.prototype === arr.__proto__.__proto__);
```

Explanation: since array in Javascript is also an Object, you can access `Object.prototype` using just `arr`.

Following will also log true:

```js
console.log(Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
console.log(Array.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```